# Javascript Split Space Delimited String and Trim Extra Commas and Spaces

Tags: javascript, string, split, trim

I need to split a keyword string and turn it into a comma delimited string. However, I need to get rid of extra spaces and any commas that the user has already input.

```
var keywordString = "ford    tempo, with,,, sunroof";
```

Output to this string:

```
ford,tempo,with,sunroof,
```

I need the trailing comma and no spaces in the final output.

Not sure if I should go Regex or a string splitting function.

Anyone do something like this already?

I need to use javascript (or JQ).

EDIT (working solution):

```
var keywordString = ", ,, ford,    tempo, with,,, sunroof,, ,";

//remove all commas; remove preceeding and trailing spaces; replace spaces with comma

str1 = keywordString.replace(/,/g , '').replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').replace(/[\s,]+/g, ',');


//add a comma at the end
str1 = str1 + ',';

console.log(str1);
```

Comment: jQuery is not a string manipulation library...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You will need a regular expression in both cases. You could split and join the string:

```
str = str.split(/[\s,]+/).join();
```

This splits on and consumes any consecutive white spaces and commas. Similarly, you could just match and replace these characters:

```
str = str.replace(/[\s,]+/g, ',');
```

For the trailing comma, just append one

```
str = .... + ',';
```

If you have preceding and trailing white spaces, you should remove those first.

**Reference:** [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: +1 This works perfectly except for one small piece. It does not have the trailing comma. Since he wants it on the final output, you may want to add it for completeness.

Comment: I am getting an extra comma if there is white space and a comma at the end. See my edit above or: http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/MraW9/

Comment: Well, why are you using so many replace functions? In addition to triming white spaces from the beginning/end, also trim commas.

Comment: Got it working. I had to replace the commas first, then the white space.

Comment: +1 Every day is a school day, wasn't aware you could split with a regex pattern.

Comment: The jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/MraW9/ does not work for correct inputs (ie "first,second,third")... to fix this, replace `(/,/g , '')` with `(/,/g , ' ')` and ensure it is the first replace

Answer (score 10):

In **ES6**:

```
var temp = str.split(",").map((item)=>item.trim());
```

Comment: The trim in this case just removes the white space.
For example , consider we get this after split 
`["foo"," bar", "  ", "foobar"]` , 
After the above function the result will be 
`["foo","bar", "", "foobar"]` .

Comment: @Rahul just add a filter func like: str.split(",").map(item=>item.trim()).filter(item=>item!=="")

Comment: adding a `trim` after the split adds a lot of overhead, the accepted answer is much more efficient since it does it in 1 pass with a regex `/[\s,]+/` compare to this answer which requires at the minimum 2 passes and the comment before mine is even worst with 3 passes

Answer (score 6):

*In addition to [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211206/259656)*

> If you have preceding and trailing white spaces, you should remove
>   those first.

It's possible to add an "extension method" to a JavaScript `String` by hooking into it's prototype. I've been using the following to trim preceding and trailing white-spaces, and thus far it's worked a treat:

```
// trims the leading and proceeding white-space
String.prototype.trim = function()
{
    return this.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple, and just match anything *not* allowed instead to join on:

```
str.split(/[^a-zA-Z-]+/g).filter(v=>v);
```

This matches all the gaps, no matter what non-allowed characters are in between. To get rid of the empty entry at the beginning and end, a simple filter for non-null values will do. See [detailed explanation on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7h851Y/1).

```js
var str = ", ,, ford,    tempo, with,,, sunroof,, ,";

var result = str.split(/[^a-zA-Z-]+/g).filter(v=>v).join(',');

console.info(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let query = "split me by space and remove trailing spaces and store in an array  ";
let words = query.trim().split(" ");
console.log(words)
```

Output :
[
'split', 'me', 'by', 'space','and','remove', 'trailing', 'spaces', 'and', 'store', 'in', 'an', 'array'
]

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to **split, trim** and **join** keeping the whitespaces, you can do this with **lodash**:

```js
// The string to fix
var stringToFix = "The Wizard of Oz,Casablanca,The Green Mile";

// split, trim and join back without removing all the whitespaces between
var fixedString = _.map(stringToFix.split(','), _.trim).join(' == ');

// output: "The Wizard of Oz == Casablanca == The Green Mile"
console.log(fixedString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```