# How can I count the unique number of phone numbers in a textarea separated with comma, newline or space?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I count the unique number of phone numbers in a `textarea` separated with comma, newline, or space in javascript or jQuery? I have tried this code:

```
$('#gsmnumbers').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#num-counter').html($('#gsmnumbers').val().split(',').length);
});
```

Comment: would be nice to see a snippet of code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: there it is, am not really good in javascript or jquery either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Split Space Delimited String and Trim Extra Commas and Spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211175/javascript-split-space-delimited-string-and-trim-extra-commas-and-spaces)

Comment: @pyanzin that's not even remotely close to a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to split the string by multiple characters:

```
var count = $('textarea').val().split(/[\n,\s]/).length;
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/61bg4juj/)

Note that you may need to sanitise the input if it's user-entered as spaces are commonly used delimiters within a phone number itself, which may lead to an incorrect count.

Comment: Thank you very much, how do i count unique numbers as 1?

Comment: Once you've got your array you can de-duplicate it, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 0):

I was exactly searching for similar answer but using someone's fiddle, I just counted for comma, space, colon, semi colon, line breaks, etc., here is the code if someone in future needs it.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzcw265y/)

```
var yay = $('textarea').val().split(/[\ \n\r\;\:\,]+/).length;
alert(yay);
```

Hope it helps someone.